# Visual studio trying to find dll when lib file was given

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors, libraries

I am trying to setup OpenCV on Visual Studio 2022. I have included the "include" folder and "lib" folder in include and library directories. I specified "opencv_world480d.lib" in the additional dependencies for the debugging version but when I run the debugger I get an error window saying "opencv_world480d.dll was not found". I want to use the static library, is there a setting in where I have to switch so that VC will use a static library? This is my first time using a library and from what I know only the lib file is needed for static library?

[additional dependencies setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7sMA.png)
[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkVgN.png)

I have tried adding the include and library directories locally and tested "opencv_world480.lib" instead of the debug version. VC still tried to find a dll file.

Comment: The static OpenCV  library will have a different name.  From the above it looks `opencv_world480d.lib` is just the stub library for the DLL.

Comment: The lib file doesn't contain the code you need, only the instructions for calling the code from the dll.

Comment: Is your problem sovled?

Comment: yes thank you. I added the bin folder to the environment path and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
opencv_world480d.dll was not found
```

You need to put the dll in the same folder as  generated exe. The dll is in opencv's x64 -> `<version>` -> bin folder.

To use static lib, make sure x64-windows-static opencv is installed.
And the lib name is different.
[image]